# Ethernet not showing 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

A friend asked me to fix this old `dell e1505` laptop. I grabbed a 32 bit version of 16.04 to throw on there.

On the live USB run it detected wireless and wired just fine. Now after installing it doesn't even detect them existing.

I don't have Internet over on that computer yet, I'm using another computer to post this, so I'm just posting screen-shots cause I don't know how to copy on one computer from terminal and paste into another.

I'm really new to Ubuntu. When I do `ifconfig -a` I'm only seeing this `lo` business, no `eth0`.

I checked my network cables and all that fun stuff and I've been trying to make sense of what I see on forums but its still just confusing. I'am very new to Linux. Any help would be appreciated. I put Ubuntu on this laptop I'm using now and didn't have these issues.

Terminal read out screen shot for `lshw`

[image]

image two is the readout from ifconfig -a

[image]

Any help would be super useful! thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your particular card requires some additional proprietary software components to be installed which come with a licence that has restrictive distribution terms, this is why Ubuntu was unable to take care of this issue for you during the install.

Seems that other users with same same installed hardware have already faced and resolved this problem as there is a wiki page which is specific to your specific issue as such I think it is probably best to refer you to the existing document.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: thanks! i tried googling some things and didnt end up there. i feel silly.

Comment: In my case I suspected that the issue would be a missing kernel driver at work here since the devices weren't presenting a functional interface that is usually the reason. So the search keywords I tried were "Linux driver BCM4311". Generally if a device is not properly registering with the system "Linux driver" and the chipset model number is a good keyword choice. Just for reference might help you or others in the future.